# Use PHP to create cron job

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to make an alarm clock with a webinterface (on my Raspberry Pi). 
I want to make this with PHP and crontab. 
This is my PHP code:

```
shell_exec("./wake.sh $minutes $hours $days");
```

This is the wake.sh script:

```
echo "number 1: $1; number 2: $2; number 3: $3" | wall;
(crontab -u $USER -l; echo "$0 $1 * * $2 /var/www/alarm.sh") | crontab -u $USER -
```

If I run the script from bash (from the www-data user), I get the broadcast message and an entry in the crontab file, but if I run it from the PHP script, the broadcast message is sent, but there is no entry in the crontab file.

Comment: Permissions. The user you are calling it in bash has permissions to execute `wake.sh`, the user under which PHP runs under (probably the webserver user) does not.

Comment: question states bash and php are both run as www-data. If so, it's not permissions or you did in fact not execute both as same user.

Comment: But if php executes this script it broadcasts from the www-data user

Comment: Moreover, doesn't every user have permissions for its own crontab?

Comment: And if I execute the script with the same user (www-data) in bash, it works! It just doesn't work when it's executed from php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the answer: the `$USER` variable is empty, if I execute it from PHP.
Now I use:

```
(crontab -l; echo "$0 $1 * * $2 /var/www/alarm.sh") | crontab -
```

and it works!