# Inserting Data into MySQL at a specific time of day

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am trying to figure out how to insert data into mysql using php. I need to insert data at several different times of the day automatically everyday. When a button is click I basically need if time is less then < 9:45 then insert '1' else if time is > 9:45 insert '2' else if time is > 12:20 insert '3' and so on. I've tried a bunch of different ways but none of them seem to work without changing my code completely.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
define('DB_NAME', 'name');
define('DB_USER', 'userr');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'passwd');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['period'];
$value2 = $_POST['name'];
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s', time());

$sql = "INSERT INTO flvs (timestamp, period, name) VALUES ('$date','$value', '$value2')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far, so we can help you (or at least we can exclude some alternatives you already consider unviable)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the time when the button in click you can get the server time (date and time functions) and check it and save. But if you want do the jobs automatically every hour or day or month you can use cronjobs.

Read these, on how to [create a cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058140/use-php-to-create-cron-job) or [cPanel cronjobs](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs).

Comment: No no the button activates that .php file i pasted. I just need that php file when its activated to insert the number 1 when activated from 9:35 to 10:40 and then insert the number 2 when activated from 10:40 to 11:40 and then anything above 11:40 will be A

Comment: in the Start of PHP File Define A Variable. Check The Time. if from 9:35 to 10:40 Set the value of the variable 1, else if from 10:40 to 11:40 set it 2 and else set it A. then insert The Variable To Database! Its The Easiest Way For Beginners.

Comment: Amir, please don't write entirely in title case - there is no need for it, and as you can see no other questions or answers are written that way. This will just create editing work for someone.

Comment: Thanks for improving it (though all lower case is not ideal either). I made some of my own improvements (e.g. spelling) which your latest edit removed, so I have reverted. You should get a JavaScript warning if edits conflict - if you see that, please back out of the edit and refresh the page, so you are looking at the latest copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO flvs (timestamp, period, name) 
select '$date', 
        case when time(now()) < '09:45:00' then '1' 
             when time(now()) > '12:20:00' then '3' 
             when time(now()) > '09:45:00' then '2' 
             else 0
        end,
       '$value2'
```

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO flvs (timestamp, name) VALUES ('$date','$value2')";

INSERT INTO flvs (period) 
select '$date'
        case when time(now()) < '09:45:00' then '1' 
             when time(now()) > '12:20:00' then '3' 
             when time(now()) > '09:45:00' then '2' 
             else 0
        end,;

Comment: yeah I can't figure this out I need to insert it into the 'period' column in my mysql database and I can't figure out to incorporate that with my exsisting code. $sql = ("INSERT INTO flvs

Comment: Can you help me incorporate this with my code. I want it to submit the numbers in 'period' which is a field on my table(visitors) in mysql. @juergen d